# Array out of bounds exception in java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

So I'm not sure where this is going out of bounds can you all point it out to me, probably its something stupid but I'm really tired and just can't find out what's going wrong. I'm getting errors on each of the openNode.indexOf()'s. Also by printing out the N value I know that N.getX() or N.getY() never reach below 1.

```
    if(N.getX() > 0)
    {
        flag = false;
        if(!isTilePassable(nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()].getX() * 32, nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()].getY() * 32)) //west
            closedNode.add(nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()]);

        for(Node e : closedNode)
            if(e.equals(openNode.indexOf(nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()])))
                flag = true;
        if(!flag)
        {
            openNode.get(openNode.indexOf(nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()])).setDistance(SRC);
            openNode.get(openNode.indexOf(nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()])).setParent(N);
        }
    }

    if(N.getY() > 0)
    {
        flag = false;
        if(!isTilePassable(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()-1].getX() * 32, nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()-1].getY() * 32)) //north
            closedNode.add(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()-1]);

        for(Node e : closedNode)
            if(e.equals(openNode.indexOf(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()-1])))
                flag = true;
        if(!flag)
        {
            openNode.get(openNode.indexOf(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()-1])).setDistance(SRC);
            openNode.get(openNode.indexOf(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()-1])).setParent(N);
        }
    }
```

here is init of nodeGrid and assigning of x+y values Node object takes parameters of x and y

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
        for(int ii = 0; ii < 25; ii++)
            nodeGrid[i][ii] = new Node(i,ii);   //initializes node grid
```

Comment: Your exception should tell you exactly where it is going out of bounds...

Comment: In what line do you get the exception? It makes it a lot easier for us to find the issue if we don't have to search everything for ourselves ;)

Comment: the problem probably is not with your `openNode.indexOf()` rather i think it is in your `nodeGrid[]` show the initialization code of the array and also give the value of `getY()` and `getX()`

Comment: each of the openNode.get(openNode.indexOf(nodeGrid[][])).setParent(); lines (added constructor in snippets)

Comment: I don't think there is enough information here. Could you construct an [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @SpiderShlong: give us the stack trace.. given from your initialization part `N.getX()` is either greater or equal to 36 or lesser than 0 and /or `N.getY()-1` is greater than or equal to 25 or lesser than 0.

Comment: Its reaching -1 but I have an if statement encompassing each of those lines of code that won't run them if the values will reach below 0. Likewise for 36 and 25.

Comment: those are the only possible solutions i could think of at the moment. it would really be easy for us if you could post the stack trace of the exception. i would also suggest you print the values of `getX()` and `getY()` before using them on `nodeGrid` so that you can see what values they fetch.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help but I figured out I just made a stupid mistake. Was using indexOf() to search through nodeGrid to retrieve X and Y Values which didn't differ from openNode, although my distance variable was different so it constantly returned -1 for the index position.

Comment: post your answer and accept it so that people may know the solution... good luck.. :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem probably is not with your `openNode.indexOf()` rather i think it is in your `nodeGrid[][]`.

given from your initialization part `N.getX()` is either greater or equal to 36 or lesser than 0 and /or `N.getY()-1` is greater than or equal to 25 or lesser than 0.

and since you have said that those values reach -1 at some point but you have added a check for that by checking `N.getxX()>0` it is still a waste of effort as you check for the `getX()' to be greater than`0`but inside that block you are using`getY()`which could be`-1`

see this

```
if(N.getX() > 0) {
// more code
if(e.equals(openNode.indexOf(nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()]))) // you are using getY
```

in here you are checking `X` but not `Y` so it may trigger the exception. more help can be provided if you give the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

`nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()]` is used with closedNode, error did not occur there,
only possibility is openNode is empty, in that case `openNode.indexOf(nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()])` will return -1,
`openNode.get(-1)` will get out of bounds exception

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your help but I figured out I just made a stupid mistake. Was using indexOf() to search through nodeGrid to retrieve X and Y Values which didn't differ from openNode, although my distance variable was different so it constantly returned -1 for the index position since there was no occurance of that variable in openNode.